# How to simplify the SPSS Syntax when repeating functions

Tags: spss

I am using SPSS syntax to run multiple UNIANOVAs for multiple variables each time under different conditions (or for different set of cases).

I always use UNIANOVA for almost same 15-20 variables with 5-30 levels. But each time I am running the analyses for different set of cases. So what I do is each time I select cases I copy the same analyses for same variables which takes up a lot of space.

However, I am just a beginner in using SPSS syntax and I am not sure if there is a way that each time I specify cases, I just ask to repeat commands from-to, rather than actually copying them all again. The point of this is, I am trying to have a shorter syntax file as I am currently getting a bit lost in it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the warning. I wasn't aware of this rule.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible ways to do this. If you analyse disjunct groups of the cases in the file, then the easiest way is to use the split file command. Suppose your grouping variable is agegroup, then the following cammands should do the job:

SORT CASES  BY agegroup.

SPLIT FILE SEPARATE BY agegroup.

Every analysis that you now execute will be performed for all of the different agegroups in your file.

Comment: For a good tutorial on this, see [SPSS SPLIT FILE](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-split-file-command/).